# The sequence of functions $\{x,x/2,x/3,...\}$ is not uniformly convergent

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, proof-verification, uniform-convergence

I want to show the sequence of real functions $(f_n)$ where $f_i(x)=\frac{x}{i}$ is not uniformly convergent, though it converges pointwise to $f=0$.

Here's my solution:

Let $\varepsilon=1$. Then given any $N$, we can let $n=N+1$ and $x=N+2$. Then $|\frac{x}{n}|=\left|\frac{N+2}{N+1}\right|>1$. Thus $|f_n-0|>\varepsilon$ and $(f_n)$ is not uniformly convergent.

My question is whether I can let $x$ depend on $n$ like that, and whether what I did was valid.

Thanks!

Comment: What's your domain? $\Bbb{R}$?

Comment: Yes, forgot to mention that.

Answer (score 1):

Your solution is fine. Here's, the same idea, with (in my opinion) an easier presentation.

> Suppose the sequence converges uniformly. Then, for all $n$ sufficiently large,
>   $$\frac{1}{n}\sup_{x\in\mathbb{R}}\left|x\right|=\sup_{x\in\mathbb{R}}\left|\frac{x}{n}-0\right|<1$$
>   This is clearly a contradiction, since $|x|$ is
>   unbounded.

This should answer your question as well: "$x$ can depend on $n$" (but not the other way around).

Comment: In this proof, isn't n depending on x? It seems like you're saying _given_ an x, we can find an n such that |x| is bounded, which is a contradiction.

Comment: No; note that $x$ is a dummy variable (I take the sup).